# Push of current branch master was rejected в Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

В Git не разбираюсь. Весь Git для меня  - это вкладка VCS в Android Studio. Это я к слову, то что весь способ ведения проекта на GitHub - это нажатие кнопочки VCS Commit.

Собственно проблема: долгое время я коммитил в GitHub через Android Studio таким образом, что мой email в профайле GitHub и email в настройках Git на компьютере не совпадали. Таким образом GitHub не распознавал мой коммиты, как коммиты от создателя репозитория. Решил сегодня поменять email в настройках Git на моем компьютере. Изменил на тот, что указан в профайле GitHub. После этого при нажатии VCS Commit появляется это:

[image: Ошибка]

Соответственно коммит не "коммитится" на GitHub и никак не отображается. Как я понимаю, это случилось из-за того, что я сменил email. Как сделать так, чтобы все опять благополучно отправлялось?

Если что ссылка на мой репозиторий: https://github.com/Drojjipivnie/newPushchinoProject

Comment: Здравствуйте @drojjipivnie. Хотелось бы уточнить: у вас локальный репозиторий последней версии?

Comment: Если это проверяется с помощью git --version, то у меня 2.6.3.windows.1. Сейчас как я понимаю существует уже версия 2.7.4. Получается не последней версии. Или вы что то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: нет. Выполните команду `git log` и посмотрите какой коммит у вас последний на локальной машине.

Comment: Получаю такое сообщение: fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

Comment: запустите `cmd`, перейдите в корневую папку вашего проекта и выполните команду `git log`

Comment: Все что он мне вывел в сообщении, это локальные коммиты, которые были сделаны через Android Studio, но не были отправлены в GitHub. Что -то похожее на номер версии не вижу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37163/discussion-between-sanek-zhitnik-and-drojjipivnie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас в локальном репозитории и в удаленном разные коммиты ссылаются на один (проще говоря нарушена последовательность односвязного списка). В вашем случае можно пойти по одному из следующих вариантов:

1. Произвести слияние коммитов (Это вам предлагает Android Studio). Для этого нужно использовать функцию `merge`. Однако, это действие подразумевает, что программист поможет Гиту разобраться в спорных ситуациях какие строки кода оставлять, а какие удалять.
2. Если есть возможность - удалить ненужные коммиты с удаленного репозитория. Для этого необходимо скопировать удаленный репозиторий в папку на ПК с помощью команды `git clone URL`. Переместить указатель HEAD - `git reset --hard HEAD~число_коммитов` и принудительно отправить на удаленный репозиторий локальный `git push origin +master`

Совет на будущее: перед каждым началом работы с проектом синхронизируйте свой локальный репозиторий с удаленным.

Comment: Вы нереально крутой, Sanek! Я долбался с этой VCS несколько дней. И так, и сяк крутил настройки Git в IDE, а оказалось, что ошибка тупо в синхронизации. +1 Вам за ответ!!!